# Time() By 5 Minutes Select

Tags: php, date

PHP Function to convert time() seconds to time format Hour:Minutes

```
function secondsToTime($seconds) {
 $dtF = new \DateTime('@0');
 $dtT = new \DateTime("@$seconds");
// return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
 return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%h:%i');
}

echo secondsToTime(time());
```

I need a function for something like:

```
If time now is 23:41 (hour:minute) to show 23:40
If time now is 23:46 (hour:minute) to show 23:45
If time now is 23:47 (hour:minute) to show 23:45
If time now is 23:49 (hour:minute) to show 23:45
If time now is 23:52 (hour:minute) to show 23:50
```

But the output to be show by time() format seconds so this way i can check via mysql how many rows updated from time() format show 23:45 if time now is 23:49 so in past 4 minutes ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to round the minutes and then reformat your output date.

There's some gotchas hidden in here. As you can end up with 60 minutes (should be `00`) and 24 hours (also should be `00`). So special checks are put in place to catch that.

Also, you way of getting the current time is very convoluted. Getting "now" gets the same value which is what `DateTime()` gets by default.

```
function secondsToTime() {
    $now      = new \DateTime();
    $cminutes = $now->format('i');
    $hour     = $now->format('H');
    $nminutes = (round($cminutes)% 5 === 0) ? round($cminutes) : round(($cminutes + 5 / 2) / 5 ) * 5;
    if ($nminutes > $cminutes) {
        $nminutes -= 5;
    }
    if ($nminutes === 60) {
        $nminutes = 0;
        $hour++;
    }
    if ($hour === 24) {
        $hour = 0;
    }
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hour, $nminutes);
}

echo secondsToTime();
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/rGP9D)

Comment: your script is making if time now is 15:07 your script is showing 15:10 but needs to be 15:05 ( hour:minutes )

Comment: Missed the part where you round down. That should be corrected.